# Can't replace [] and ; in filename of the file uploaded

Tags: javascript, regex

```
refName = function () {
    var fileName = document.getElementById('import').value;

    fileName = fileName.replace(/[&\/#,+()[];$~%@^'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
    var str = fileName.split("\\"); //to strip path from filename
}
```

I am passing the file name of the file uploaded to the above function i am able to remove all the Regex except [] and ; from file name, any help appreciated

Comment: Need to escape the square brackets in character class. Use `/[&\/#,+()\[\];$~%@^'":*?<>{}]/g`

Comment: Also, pick one language

Comment: If you just want alphanumeric characters in string use `.replace(/\W+/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
result = subject.replace(/[&\/#,+()[\];$~%@^'":*?<>{}]/g, "");
```

The special chars `[`, `]` are needed to be escaped.

Comment: You forgot the character class and no need to escape the braces `{}`.